# Write event handler for Controls in Resource Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

How to write events for the `Controls/Templates` that are defined in `ResourceDictionary`?

For now I've to use `event to command strategy` and write `Commands` in `ViewModels(DataContext)` for every control and for every `event`. See below code how can I write `TextChanged` event in `ResourceDictionary` :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

                >

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="MyTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox Width="500" Background="LightGreen" TextChanged="TextChanged" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this we needs to write a class file for `ResourceDictionary` using `x:class` :

```
public partial class ResourceDictionary
{
    //...
}
```

and need to specify that `class` in `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="YourNamespace.ResourceDictionary"
                    >

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="MyTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBox Width="500" Background="LightGreen" TextChanged="TextChanged" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```